# Which kind of stores carry packing materials to use when moving?

Tags: relocation, israel

I need to move apartments, outside of or within Israel. What kind of stores should I look for packing materials in?

Specifically, relevant items can be:

- Cardboard boxes, at least [double-wall](https://www.packsize.com/green/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/types-of-corrugated.png) corrugated, of various sizes.
- Rolls of [bubble-wrap](https://www.airseacontainers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Man-holding-a-roll-of-plastic-bubble-wrap.jpg) (~0,5 wide and maybe ~1m wide)
- Adhesive [packing tape](https://www.tesa.com/en-gb/files/images/201608/15/tesapack-packaging-tapes-and-carton-sealing-tapes,126680_fixedwidth_4.webp) (~5-10 cm wide)
- [Adhesive plastic film](https://5.imimg.com/data5/BE/AS/MY-3359890/vci-film-500x500.png) rolls
- Adhesive stickers (numbered or unnumbered, ~5cm x ~5cm)

Would I be better served visiting...

- Large do-It-Yourself / home repair stores?
- Small neighborhood "hardware stores"
- Specialty stores for packing equipment (if those even exist)?
- Online venues which offer such items?
- Other kinds of stores?

Comment: I've only spent a few hours in Israel, but here in the US I would expect to find most of these things at a large DIY store and whatever I didn't find there I would expect to find in an office supply store.  (I would expect the office supply store to have it all, but at higher prices than the DIY store.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: I have found such items mostly at the large DIY chain stores and on a specialty website (a single one I know of).**

#### Cartons / cardboard boxes

Carton recycling/disposal cages are quite common in Israel. You will typically find them near large super-market stores, oper-air markets, and in some industrial zones. The latter are probably the best source of clean, good-condition cartons, but all of them are useful to raid.

Mid-to-large-size DIY/home improvement stores, specifically the [Home Center](https://www.homecenter.co.il/) and [Ace](https://www.ace.co.il/) chain stores, will offer a limited selection of box sizes (e.g. [this](https://www.ace.co.il/1701065.html) or [these](https://www.homecenter.co.il/catalogue/root?kw=%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9F)). These may be available for delivery as well. Note that in some locations, these stores are smaller and carry onlyl some of their catalog (and packing materials are not very high priority).

Specialty sites (the only one I know at the moment is getmoving.co.il) offer a wider selection and also kits of multiple boxes in various sizes (by total number of items).

#### Adhesive film

Home Center [carries this](https://www.homecenter.co.il/catalogue/root?kw=%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%93): 10-cm wide and 50-cm wide.

Ace [carries](https://www.ace.co.il/1607046.html) what looks like 25-cm adhesive film rolls.

GetMoving [carries](https://shop.getmoving.co.il/p/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A3) the 10-cm variety (cheaper, it seems), as well as a [plastic applicator handle](https://shop.getmoving.co.il/p/%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A3) for it.

#### Bubble-wrap

Ace [carries](https://www.ace.co.il/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A4%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9D) 50-cm width and 100-cm width bubble wrap rolls.

HomeCenter also [carries](https://www.homecenter.co.il/catalogue/root?kw=%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA) 50-cm width and 100-cm rolls.

GetMoving [carries](https://shop.getmoving.co.il/page/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94) four varieties (scroll down to find them) : 50cm x 25m, 50cm x 75m, 100cm x 25m, 100cm x 75m.

#### One-stop-shop websites:

Some web sleuthing yielded:

- ["Everything for the mover"](https://www.hakol-lamovil.co.il/) (Hakol La-Movil)
- ["Get Moving"](https://shop.getmoving.co.il/)
- ["Shop-Move"](https://shop.hovala.co.il/) (Shop-Hovala) - website seems a bit dodgy, as if it replicates contents to fit what you searched for. It may still be legit though.

These offer essentially all of the items OP asked about, and the latter even offers storage space.